# $_SESSION variables not working on server (PHP)

Tags: php, session

I've seen this question asked and there seem to be a lot of random solutions to the problem but I can't seem to get to the bottom of mine.

I've set up a simple PHP login script that saves some `$_SESSION` variables and it works fine on localhost when I test it from my computer. When I've uploaded it to our VPS, it doesn't work and I've pinpointed it to a problem with the variables not being carried over between pages.

I have `session_start()` at the beginning of each page in the connect file that I'm including for my database connection (and as I said, it works fine on my localhost).

I read that sometimes it is a server settings issue. Here is my `phpinfo()` below (for the SESSION variable part) and everything seems to be enabled correctly. I did not see the /var/lib/php/session folder but I created it with the thought that maybe it wasn't able to store them because it didn't exist. That didn't fix the problem.

I tried to do an `ini_set()` to explicitly set the path in my files and there was no luck there either.

Any ideas on what it could be? I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is this a load balanced server by any chance?

Comment: Your server can write to that session save path?

Comment: @Progrock, I'm not entirely sure. What would be a good way to test that?

Comment: @Tigger, no load balancing on this server...

Comment: Re: folder perms, depends on how you are running Php.  Are you using Php-fpm?

Comment: Is the server in a pool?

Comment: @Progrock, I'm sorry, I'm not very well versed in the questions you are asking. The details I know are that this is a VPS so I would have control over editing certain aspects of the PHP install (it's not on a shared environment, etc.).

Comment: Try searching for session related issues for your VPS provider.  If Php can't write to your session directory, then I'd expect an error of that sort in the error logs.  A _temporary_ way to grant write access to your session folder is to give it world writeable permissions.  Server platform/config. dictates the correct set up.  I'd discuss this problem with your host.  Do write up your solution, if found.